# How to gnuplot - replot for two different equations in png terminal?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to fit curves on different files to get them inside single png.
I am using the following code :

```
set terminal png enhanced font arial 14 size 800,600
set key outside horizontal left
f(x) = a*x**b
b = 1
a = 10000
fit f(x) 'a.txt' via a,b
plot 'a.txt' with dots  lc rgb"red" title ' ', \
f(x) with lines lc rgb"red" title sprintf('Curve Equation:   f(x) = %.2f·x^{%.2f}', a, b )


f1(x) = c*exp(d*x)
d = -1
c = 10000
fit f1(x) 'b.txt' via c,d
plot 'b.txt' with dots  lc rgb"red" title ' ', \
f1(x) with lines lc rgb"blue" title sprintf('Curve Equation:   f1(x) = %.2f·e^{-.%.2f.x}', c, d )

replot

unset output 
exit gnuplot;
```

What might be missing in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `replot` is usually a bad choice when writing to a file.

Basically you have two choices:

1. Write all plot informations in a single `plot` command (I left out the `fit` stuff for clarity):

   ```
   set terminal pngcairo enhanced font arial 14 size 800,600
   set output 'output.png'
   # do some fitting

   set style data dots
   set style function lines
   plot 'a.txt' lc rgb "red" title ' ', \
        f(x) lc rgb "red" title sprintf('Curve Equation:   f(x) = %.2f·x^{%.2f}', a, b), \
        'b.txt' lc rgb "red" title ' ', \
        f1(x) lc rgb"blue" title sprintf('Curve Equation:   f1(x) = %.2f·e^{-.%.2f.x}', c, d )
   ```
2. If you want to separate the two plotting blocks you need some tricking with different terminals, use `replot ...` for all but the first plot block and you must set the `png` terminal and the output file only directly before the last `replot`:

   ```
   set style data dots
   set style function lines

   set terminal unknown
   # do fitting of f(x)
   plot 'a.txt' lc rgb "red" title ' ', \
        f(x) lc rgb "red" title sprintf('Curve Equation:   f(x) = %.2f·x^{%.2f}', a, b)

   # do fitting of f1(x)
   set terminal pngcairo enhanced font arial 14 size 800,600
   set output 'output.png'
   replot 'b.txt' lc rgb "red" title ' ', \
        f1(x) lc rgb"blue" title sprintf('Curve Equation:   f1(x) = %.2f·e^{-.%.2f.x}', c, d )

   unset output
   ```
3. This is a variant of 2 for the case that you want to specify the final terminal at the beginning of the script. You can save the current terminal with `set terminal push` and restore it later with `set terminal pop`:

   ```
   set terminal pngcairo enhanced font arial 14 size 800,600
   output_file = 'output.png'
   set style data dots
   set style function lines

   set terminal push
   set terminal unknown
   # do fitting of f(x)
   plot 'a.txt' lc rgb "red" title ' ', \
        f(x) lc rgb "red" title sprintf('Curve Equation:   f(x) = %.2f·x^{%.2f}', a, b)

   # do fitting of f1(x)
   set terminal pop
   set output output_file
   replot 'b.txt' lc rgb "red" title ' ', \
        f1(x) lc rgb"blue" title sprintf('Curve Equation:   f1(x) = %.2f·e^{-.%.2f.x}', c, d )

   unset output
   ```

Comment: **Option:2** is a better way, was Helpful.

Comment: I added a third option which is similar to 2 but allows you to set the final terminal at the beginning.